# I want to extract the video link out of youtube embed code, I am searching for a regex solution for this

Tags: php, regex

For example: an youtube embed code

```
<object width="480" height="385">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/TFlzeO267qY&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TFlzeO267qY&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

I want to extract `http://www.youtube.com/v/TFlzeO267qY&hl=en_US&fs=1&"` from this embed code but I dont know how to create a regex expression for this

Thanks in Advance?

Comment: Googling for 'youtube link regex' would have turned up a number of possibilities. I'm too lazy to test one and copy/paste it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this code is what you need .. try it and maybe it will help you to  understand ***regex*** :

```
$var = '<object width="480" height="385">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/TFlzeO267qY&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TFlzeO267qY&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>';
preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/', $var, $src);
$src = $src[1];
echo $src;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the example link you provided:

```
http://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/v/[\w&=]+
```

You'll need to escape the slashes so that they are still part of the regex.

Comment: I am new to regex, so can you please tell me the full syntax to retrieving out the link